# Relationship between device queue_depth and HBA ql2xmaxqdepth

Tags: fibre-channel

RHEL 6/7 server with dual-port FC hba:
There's a queue which may be adjusted via the QLogic HBAs ql2xmaxqdepth kernel-module parameter. And there's a queue for each block device, eg /sys/block/sdf/device/queue_depth

How do the two relate? If I want to increase the server's SAN overall I/O queue depth, should I do it using one or the other?